# Алгоритм определения редактирования фото

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Как определить, были ли внесены изменения в изображение? В просторах инета нашел метод ELA, однако реализацию данного метода в c# не нашел

Comment: Вы бы формализовали задачу как-нибудь. Была полностью чёрная картинка, её поменяли на полностью белую, метаданные стёрты. Как определить, чтобы было редактирование?

Comment: Влад, ну зачем же так) Допустим есть человек без переднего зуба, мы в фотошопе нарисовали ему его)

Comment: А так по теме - не нашел ни одного решения.

Comment: Думаю, тут сложно найти гарантированное математически решение. Так, какие-то приближения, типа использование клонирования или блюр. Но если подделку делал специалист...

Comment: А почему просто не смотреть на изменение _файла_? Файл не поменялся — значит, изображение не редактировалось.

Comment: я хочу узнать просто по картинке - внесены ли в нее изменения. http://fotoforensics.com/ вот например

Comment: если сравнить рядом стоящие пиксели с тем местом где редактировали, то любые изменения типа клонирования фотошоповского видны при увеличении на глаз даже не специалисту исключительно и банально по шуму вокруг

Answer (score 2):

ELA - это анализ ошибок сжатия jpeg, он применим если изображение редактировалось уже после сжатия (т.е. кто-то, например, переписал jpeg с камеры и уже потом подфотошопил). Он достаточно легко реализуется с помощью OpenCV.

Для .net есть готовые обёртки поверх [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) - библиотеки для работы с изображениями - [OpenCV.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCV.Net/), [Emgu](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

Берете любой [пример ELA под OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27648073/1988244) и просто переводит его на C# - разница будет буквально на уровне синтаксиса:

```
// Control
int scale = 15,
    quality = 75;

// Image containers
cv::Mat input_image,
    compressed_image;

void processImage(int, void*)
{
   // Setting up parameters and JPEG compression
   std::vector<int> parameters;
   parameters.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
   parameters.push_back(quality);
   cv::imwrite("temp.jpg", input_image, parameters);

   // Reading temp image from the disk
   compressed_image = cv::imread("temp.jpg");

   if (compressed_image.empty())
   {
      std::cout << "> Error loading temp image" << std::endl;
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   cv::Mat output_image = cv::Mat::zeros(input_image.size(), CV_8UC3);

   // Compare values through matrices
   for (int row = 0; row < input_image.rows; ++row)
   {
    const uchar* ptr_input = input_image.ptr<uchar>(row);
    const uchar* ptr_compressed = compressed_image.ptr<uchar>(row);
    uchar* ptr_out = output_image.ptr<uchar>(row);

        for (int column = 0; column < input_image.cols; column++)
        {
            // Calc abs diff for each color channel multiplying by a scale factor
            ptr_out[0] = abs(ptr_input[0] - ptr_compressed[0]) * scale;
            ptr_out[1] = abs(ptr_input[1] - ptr_compressed[1]) * scale;
            ptr_out[2] = abs(ptr_input[2] - ptr_compressed[2]) * scale;

            ptr_input += 3;
            ptr_compressed += 3;
            ptr_out += 3;
        }
    }

    // Shows processed image
    cv::imshow("Error Level Analysis", output_image);
}
```